# How can I execute a script inside an Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have one lib/ folder inside my Eclipse Plugin Project and on this folder I have a little script... But when I run the 'Eclipse Plugin Project' I cannot execute that script because I cannot access to that folder...

How can I fix this?

--
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can execute the script by passing an `InputStream` or a `String` to the interpreter, put in the `src/` folder, so it ends up on the classpath and use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("script-name")` to get an `InputStream`

If the interpreter is external (like `bash` or something that doesn't implement the Java Scripting API), do the same. When you need to execute the script, create a stream and copy the script to a temporary file.

Keeping the script in `lib/` is also a bad idea since the plugin will be assembled into a single JAR file unless you turn that off, so you will end up with a script file inside of a JAR - again something which most interpreters can't use.

By using the classpath, you can let Eclipse figure out where the data is.

Comment: Actually, my "script" is a binary file (executable file)... How can I create a stream and copy the binary file to a temporary executable file?!

Comment: Create a temporary file with `File.createTempFile()`, open an `OutputStream` for it, copy the `InputStream` you got from the classpath (see code above).